# How does one instantiate Spring in the context of a library?

Tags: spring

I'm looking for an example which shows how to instantiate a Spring container within the context of a set of classes packaged in a plain old, non-executable java library/JAR. The core purpose here is provide dependency injection (primarily for logging)

The fundamental problem as I see it is that a non-executable jar has no single startup point - no main method. So how do I go about creating and configuring the necessary application context?

Answer (score 1):

Well your framework has to provide the necessary starting point somehow of course, e.g. a factory method that the user of your library has to call somewhere. An alternative would be to use a static block which will be executed as soon as the class has been loaded, e.g.:

```
public class BootStrap
{
    private static final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    public static ApplicationContext getContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    private BootStrap() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unless I'm missing something, the static block is what I was looking for. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

See the Spring chapter on ["Glue Code and The Evil Singleton"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/beans.html#beans-servicelocator). This describes how to bootstrap Spring in cases where it's not provided as part of a container lifecycle, using [ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/access/ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.html). Spring will handle the distasteful process of maintaining a singleton reference to the context, which your JAR code can access at its leisure. No entry point or startup routines required, it's performed lazily on demand.

Comment: This http://book.javanb.com/Professional-Java-Development-with-the-Spring-Framework/BBL0090.html article provided an example and helped fill out the info from above

Answer (score 0):

Apache CXF contains code for this. However, to be honest, it's about 5 lines of code.