# Creating Spring context in a library

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am developing a library which will be used from a non-Spring application. However, I need to use another library which is developed for a work in Spring context and want to also use Spring features like dependency injection. So, I need to create a Spring `ApplicationContext` in my library and include dependency library into it. To demonstrate the situation, I have an example project with two modules:

[image: Project structure]

Root project pom.xml (lib-with-spring-dep):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-with-spring-dep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>lib</module>
        <module>spring-lib</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml (lib):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>lib-with-spring-dep</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>lib</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml (spring-lib):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>lib-with-spring-dep</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spring-lib</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

SpringService.java:

```
package org.example.springlib;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SpringService {

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Message";
    }
}
```

Executor.java:

```
package org.example.lib;

import org.example.springlib.SpringService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Executor {

    @Autowired
    private SpringService service;

    public String getMessageFromService() {
        return service.getMessage();
    }
}
```

TestExecutor.java:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

import org.example.lib.Executor;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestExecutor {

    @Test
    public void testSpringContext() {
        String message = new Executor().getMessageFromService();
        Assert.assertThat(message, is("Message"));
    }
}
```

Running the test gives the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.example.lib.Executor.getMessageFromService(Executor.java:14)
    at TestExecutor.testSpringContext(TestExecutor.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

How can I create a Spring context in the `lib` library?
There was also an answered question [How does one instantiate Spring in the context of a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502064/how-does-one-instantiate-spring-in-the-context-of-a-library), but it was almost 12 years ago, and I hope there are some new options to achieve this.

Comment: It sounds like your design is flawed.  SUGGESTION: 1) your app's toplevel should be Spring.  2) If you want to use "Spring" capabilities in certain classes or methods in your library ... then those should probably be loaded from Spring, e.g. as a [Spring Bean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean).

Comment: @paulsm4 My top-level app is not under my control, and it does not use Spring. The dependency library, which uses Spring, is also used from other application which has its own Spring context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer here [Designing a Java library with Spring](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1518480). I have added new class `BeanFactory` to the `lib` module:

```
package org.example.lib;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")
public class BeanFactory {

    private static ApplicationContext context;
    
    private static ApplicationContext getContext() {
         if (context == null) {
             context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanFactory.class);
         }
         return context;
    }
    
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return getContext().getBean(requiredType);
    }
}
```

and modified the `Executor` class:

```
package org.example.lib;

import org.example.springlib.SpringService;

public class Executor {

    public String getMessageFromService() {
        SpringService service = BeanFactory.getBean(SpringService.class);
        return service.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Now the `BeanFactory` serves simultaneously as an entry point for accessing the `ApplicationContext` and as a configuration class. The configuration can be a separate class as well.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that solution since Spring provides support for testing, no need to impl hacks, see my answer above

Comment: To eHayik: The test class simulates the situation when the lib library is called from a non-Spring application where Spring context is unavailable. The task is to create a Spring context in the lib library itself to use it in any dependency libraries.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, either way I would recommend to look for a better solution, since this one is hard to test and as I mention above is a hack. top-level app should be in charge of loading the application context, getting rid of @Autowired in favor of Constructor Injection might help. In addition it isn't thread safe